# Command hangs: `run(pipeline(`git --no-pager diff`, stderr=err, stdout=out), wait=true)`

Tags: julia

*Note: this question was asked previously at [discourse.julialang.org](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/command-hangs-run-pipeline-git-diff-stderr-err-stdout-out-wait-true/103742) but wasn't resolved. The issue occurred while debugging DrWatson.jl ([#300](https://github.com/JuliaDynamics/DrWatson.jl/issues/300))*

This works fine in a git repository (with changed files):

```
julia> run(`git --no-pager diff`)
```

**However, when manually capturing the output with**

```
julia> out = Pipe(); err = Pipe(); 
julia> run(pipeline(`git --no-pager diff`, stderr=err, stdout=out), wait=true)
```

**the command never finishes. Why?**

### My reproducible way to set up a git repo with changed file:

```
shell> mkdir JuliaGitWithPipeHangs
shell> cd JuliaGitWithPipeHangs
shell> git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /mnt/data/git/tmp/JuliaGitWithPipeHangs/.git/
julia> using Random; write("tmp.txt", string(rand(MersenneTwister(42), 10000)))
shell> git add tmp.txt
shell> git commit -m"commit"
julia> write("tmp.txt", string(rand(MersenneTwister(42), 100)))
```

## Versions

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.9.3
Commit bed2cd540a1 (2023-08-24 14:43 UTC)
Build Info:
  Official https://julialang.org/ release
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-linux-gnu)
  CPU: 8 × 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-14.0.6 (ORCJIT, tigerlake)
  Threads: 1 on 8 virtual cores

# git version 2.34.1
```

Comment: The given `run(pipeline(...` call executes fine for me, and returns with `ProcessExited(0)` (i.e. no errors). Are you reusing the `Pipe` objects, or doing something else different?

Comment: I'm running Julia in an empty environment, set up the git folder (as shown) and run just the commands as shown from the REPL. I should note that with `git status`, it works fine.

Comment: Since the issue seems not to reproduce, I updated the question with more information about my system.